# Easy to read Google search URL agurment _Image Tab Results_: q=how+to+create+google+search+url+argument+open+images+view+only

Tags: google-search, url, google-image-search

I like to be able to create **easy to read URLs** and I want to know how to modify the google search URL so that the *results* return showing the _image_I cannot see how to open Google results on images tab only. I'd basically like to create a URL that **reduces keystrokes or usage of the mouse.** I'd also like it to be readable and easy to create. :-)

I can create a simple URL such as:

> https://www.google.co.uk/#q=how%20to%20create%20google%20search%20url%20argument%20open%20images%20view%20only

Or more readable like in the question title above:

> q=how+to+create+google+search+url+argument+open+images+view+only

But, ***is there a query string parameter that I can add so the results returned open on the image view as a first visible choice? I don't know how to do that with Google?*** :-(

**Added bonus:** Trying to open the results on this search! >.<

> https://www.google.co.uk/#q=gif+baby+koala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gif+baby+koala&tbm=isch

The parameter you need is `tbm=isch` (which I imagine stands for "image search").